# How to solve $\binom k n$, when $k \le n$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was reading a research paper and trying to dig in deep. The authors, at one point, have come to a formula with $\sum_{k=1}^n$ $k \choose n$

I will really appreciate if someone can tell me how I can solve this thing. Especially how I can solve in Matlab. For reference, the actual equation is below.[image]

Comment: Did you mean $\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$

Comment: Yes. See eq. 19 in the image

Comment: Change your question then, your question has a typo.

Comment: No No.... I just re-read your comment. I meant what I asked in the question. Not what you said in your comment. See the eq. 19 in the image. summation is from $k= 1 \to n$, where as $C^k_n$

Comment: In that case, it is $\binom{1}{n}+\binom{2}{n}+...\binom{n}{n} = \binom{n}{n} = 1$ since all other terms are 0.

Comment: Are you sure that the symbol $C^k_n$ means $\binom kn$? Can you tell us what research paper you are reading (and provide a link if it's available on the web), or is that a secret (e.g. are you refereeing it)?